# How to parse an Excel file using javascript code in html

Tags: javascript, excel, cross-browser

I want to parse an excel file in javascript function module that can be invoked from html. I have used ActiveXobject for opening the excel sheet, but not all browsers allow opening of activexobject and alert message is not shown in all of the browsers. I need to know if there exists any other method of opening excel sheet from javascript code and is supported by all the browsers

Comment: there is already a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784681/how-to-use-javascript-to-open-excel-html-file-in-excel-application

Comment: I don't think you're going to find a good cross browser solution as ActiveX only works in Internet Explorer.  I think this is a task best left to server side processing.

Answer (score 0):

Not without browser add-ons, which your users would have to install first.

Proprietary format equals lack of 3rd-party support.

Answer (score 0):

I use a method similar to the one outlined on [this site](http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html).